# How to create SSH tunnel with PuTTY to connect Neo4j database

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

In my school work I have to use computer on which is installed Neo4j database client. I want to connect to this computer from my laptop. I had this configuration set but my system crashed and now I don't know how to do this.

My tutor send me this:

```
ssh [login]@["address"] -p 10022
```

Tunnel

```
ssh [login]@["address"] -p 10022 -L7474:localhost:7474
```

And I configured it this way in PuTTY:

[image]

In tunnel config I typed `7474:localhost:7474` into *Source port* block and `[login]@["address"]:10022` into *Destination*.

When I press *Open*, it starts, I type my password to log in but when I type `localhost:7474` in my browser, the site will not load.
I suppose that information which have been sent to me are correct. Did I something wrong? Please can somebody explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `-L` switch of `ssh` is

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

where

- `port` (`7474`) is an equivalent of *Source port* in PuTTY
- `host:hostport` (`localhost:7474`) is an equivalent of *Destination* in PuTTY

The `login@address` is not part of tunnel configuration.

The two commands you got from tutor are not to be used together. The first is normal SSH login. The latter is SSH login that also creates a tunnel. What you want to mimic is the latter command only.